# Is there a card that cancels the Legendary Rule?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

For example, I am wanting to make token copies of a legendary creature such as Progenitus using something like Progenitor Mimic. I know this is illegal by itself, but does there exist a card that would allow this?

Comment: FYI, Brothers Yamazaki cancel the rule for themselves

Comment: @IvoBeckers They don't exactly cancel it entirely. They ignore it if there are 2, but if there are 3 it still applies and each player can only keep 1.

Comment: Note, you can in fact copy Progenitus with Progenitor Mimic.

Comment: I believe what Waterseas is saying is that it's not illegal to use Progenitor Mimic as you described. Yes, the Legendary rule might kick in, but that doesn't make it illegal.

Comment: You may already be able to copy progenitus with progenitor mimic, but the mimic's ability would be useless, as the token copies it makes would all be legendary creatures. Hence, why I needed to cancel the legend rule.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The card you are looking for is [Mirror Gallery](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mirror%20Gallery), which is an artifact with the text

> The "legend rule" doesn't apply.

In addition, [Lazav, Dimir Mastermind](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Lazav%2C%20Dimir%20Mastermind) and [Sakashima the Impostor](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Sakashima%20the%20Impostor) become copies of other creatures, but they keep their own names, so they can copy other legendary creatures without dying due to the legend rule.

Comment: If you are looking in standard I would say spark double is an example of a card that breaks the Legend rule.

Comment: And now we have a new card that does this effect as well, Mirror Box!